# Как избежать ошибки telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Нужно было написать бота для сохранения сообщений из телеграм канала. Хотелось бы, чтобы он обновлял созданный им же json файл с записями сообщений, как только в канале появляется новое сообщение. Я просто обернула циклом вызов функции обновления файла, но получила ошибку `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError`. Как я поняла, ТГ забанил за слишком частые запросы серверу. Как избежать этого? Может, есть идеи, как сделать обновление json только при появлении нового сообщения в канале, а не просто проверять его каждую секунду? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Решение [от телетона](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/errors.html):

```
from telethon import errors
try:
  messages = await client.get_messages(chat)
  print(messages[0].text)
except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
  print('Have to sleep', e.seconds, 'seconds')
  time.sleep(e.seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Быть может, это поможет:
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.newmessage.NewMessage

Пример кода:

```
import asyncio
from telethon import events

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='(?i)hello.+'))
async def handler(event):
    # Respond whenever someone says "Hello" and something else
    await event.reply('Hey!')

@client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=True, pattern='!ping'))
async def handler(event):
    # Say "!pong" whenever you send "!ping", then delete both messages
    m = await event.respond('!pong')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await client.delete_messages(event.chat_id, [event.id, m.id])
```

Просто попробуй проверять с пустым паттерном, а в функции реализовать передачу сообщения в json

Comment: Спасибо, программа начала работать как надо, но теперь появился значительный delay перед появлением сообщения в json - файле. При банальном зацикливании Get.history сообщения сохранялись быстрее, чем появлялись в самом телеграме. Может, Вы знаете, как избежать задержки?

Comment: ссылка нерабочая )

Answer (score 0):

Решила проблему использованием другой библиотеки. Обратила внимание на Pyrogram, оказалось что она быстрее и проще. Никаких ошибок не возникало.